# Prove $\log_{x+5}^25 \cdot \log_5(x^2-x-6)=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Prove $\log_{x+5}^25 \cdot \log_5(x^2-x-6)=1$

Basically, I wanted to write log base $\mod{x+5}^2$ 5 but I wasn't able to write it. If anyone can just let me know how to do that I will be really grateful. Also I wanted to know Why mod(x+5}^2 will not be equal to 1. How to solve this problem?
Please don't downvote it guys.

Comment: Do you mean $\log_{(x+5)^2}{5}$?  The exponent must be in the brackets containing the subscript if you want to put it there. (The brackets around the 5 (the number you are taking the log of) are optional, but I like to use them to keep track of the number I am taking the log of.)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure where mod comes in, but I have seen the related notation $\mathbb{Z}_m$ for the set of integers mod m, but in the case of logs, I don't think the base is referred to using "mod"; I refer to it as the "base" always

Comment: Side note: Downvoters will certainly think before downvoting, maybe some of them will upvote too. I like this unique way of ending a question. :-P

Answer (score 0):

I will assume the problem should state

$$\left(\log_{(x+5)^2}{5}\right)\cdot\left(\log_5{(x^2-x-6)}\right)=1.$$

To solve this, a common property of logs is that

$$\log_a{b}=\frac{1}{\log_b{a}}.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I did the same thing @alphacapture but I couldn't understand how mod of $(x+5)^2$ is not equal to 1 and will be greater than 0 as given in the solution

Comment: I just did the calculation to check, and it's working out for me.  Can  you show your calculations so I can see how you are getting your conclusion?  (Also please don't call the "base" the "mod" or else it will be hard for others to understand you.)

Answer (score 0):

The domain is $(x+5)^2>0$, $(x+5)^2\neq1$ and $x^2-x-6>0$.

Hence, we need to solve
$$\log_5(x^2-x-6)=\log_5(x+5)^2$$ or
$$x^2-x-6=x^2+10x+25$$ or
$$x=-\frac{31}{11}$$
and checking of the domain gives the answer: $\{-\frac{31}{11}\}$.

Now, why $(x+5)^2\neq1$.

If we write $\log_ab$ then by the definition of $\log$ we need $a>0$, $a\neq1$ and $b>0$.

But let we wrote $\log_12$ and let $\log_12=a$.

Thus, $1^a=2$ and what we'll do with this thing?

Comment: why $(x+5)^2≠1$? @MichaelRozenberg what is the problem if we write   a≠1?

Comment: I got it @MichaelRozenberg. What an answer. Amazing. You just cleared my concept

Comment: @onlymaths I am very glad for you!

Comment: Just one more question emerged while doing this @MichaelRozenberg What if for example, I write $log_11=a$...then we can write it as 1^a=1. That would have made sense

Comment: @onlymaths OK. $1^a=1$. You are right! But $\log_11$ does not exist by definition!